# Why doesn't connected React component update after redux store change?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux, react-hooks

I am curious, why this can happen. I know, that everything is working as expected and I misunderstand something in this behaviour. I am using new hooks api both for react-redux and react.

```
const Categories = () => {
    const dispatch = useDispatch();
    const categoriesList = useSelector((state) => state.categories.categoriesList, shallowEqual);
    // const isFetching = useSelector((state) => state.categories.isFetching);
    console.log(categoriesList, 'categoriesList');
    useEffect(() => {
        dispatch(getCategoriesList());
        dispatch(getTemplatesList());
    }, [dispatch]);

    return (
        <ul className='categories-list'>
            {categoriesList.map((category) => {
                const {Fields: {Title, ID, IsActive, Path} = {}, SubCategoryList = []} = category;

                return (
                    <CategoryItem
                        isActive={IsActive}
                        categoriesList={categoriesList}
                        categoryID={ID}
                        // isFetching={isFetching}
                        changeCategoryStatus={changeCategoryStatusRequest}
                    />
                );
            })}
        </ul>
    );
};
```

The structure of `categoriesList` is as this

```
[
    {Info: {/**some info */}, SubCategoryList: [/**same structur like categoriesList */]},
    {Info: {/**some info */}, SubCategoryList: [/**same structur like categoriesList */]},
    {Info: {/**some info */}, SubCategoryList: [/**same structur like categoriesList */]},
    {Info: {/**some info */}, SubCategoryList: [/**same structur like categoriesList */]},
    {Info: {/**some info */}, SubCategoryList: [/**same structur like categoriesList */]},
];
```

Inside my *CategoryItem* component after clicking some button, it dispatches an action, which fetches new data for certain category with the main purpose of changing the property `isActive`.
After getting new data, I update `categoriesList` and it could be the X level deepest category, whose `isActive` prop gonna change. After changing it, it is assumed that `categoriesList` has been updated (even deeply) . But my component doesn't run again and doesn't update `isActive` status. Actually component receives that prop, and I thought, it should be rerendered. 
You can notice, that I commented `isFetching` property (It is also changed after fetching new data and updating `categoriesList`). With that property, my component renders again and changes `isActive` prop. 
At first glance I thought, that the problem is deeply nested value, but I tested it with another react-redux project in `sandbox`. In this case, the component gets rendered after `value` changes.

```
deep: {
    deep2: {
      value: 0
    }
  }
```

So what is the main difference? How can I understand it properly?
Thanks in advance.

**UPDATED** - `Here is my reducer`

```
import * as types from '../types';
import {createReducer} from '../../helpers/utilities';
import _ from 'lodash';

const initialState = {
    categoriesList: [],
    actionResult: null,
    isFetching: false,
    category: {},
};

const changeCategoryStatus = (state, action) => {
    const {payload} = action;

    const updateFunction = (category) => {
        if (category.Fields.ID === payload.ID) {
            category.Fields.IsActive = payload.IsActive;
            return false;
        }
        Array.isArray( category.SubCategoryList) && _.forEach(category.SubCategoryList, updateFunction);
    };

    const changedCategoriesList = _.forEach(state.categoriesList, updateFunction);

    return updateStore(state, {
        actionResult: hasError(payload) ? {
            type: 'error',
            message: payload.message,
        } : null,
        isFetching: false,
        categoriesList: changedCategoriesList,
    });
};

const handlers = {
    [types.CATEGORY_STATUS_RESPONSE]: changeCategoryStatus,
};

export default createReducer(initialState, handlers);
```

Comment: Can you show your reducer?

Comment: @markerikson see updated version.

Comment: where is `updateStore` coming from?